# ASP.NET AJAX Progress Indication with Async Server Calls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I know this question has been asked before..a lot in fact. But I can't seem to get the wheels turning on this thing. To be honest I'm a bit lost on mating client side and server scripting and the examples I've seen are either far to simplistic or way above my head.

Goal:
My goal is to take a long running process I've writtin in VB.NET on the server, which happens to be loop based, and calculate a percentage complete (I know the range of the index values) and relay that back to the user by some means.

Idea:
As the loop iterates I want to pass back up to the client an integer of percent complete or poll it from the client.

What I've done:
Is very limited, I have little to no experience here, I've been doing a lot of googling and I've played with the UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress controls from AJAX a bit, but this method so far seems to lean towards an idicator, like GIF.

As always any help is appreciated, and if I can answer any questions I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using an inline frame (iFrame) to host your long running process and report back status to the client via the `Response` object of the long running .aspx page?

If so, then I suggest you read [Easy incremental status updates for long requests](http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/).

The example uses a button as the display for the progress after the user clicks it, but you could direct output to another DOM element if you wish.

Comment: This looks interesting. I've read a few of his other articles but I have not come across this one yet. Using this method would I be correct in assuming that the button click I have taken care of with VB behind the page, would need to be pulled out and a new "script" aspx page created? That the iFrame will then reference, correct?

Comment: @TylerAdkins - yes, you are correct that your current button click handler code should be pulled out into a new aspx page and referenced by the iframe. On a side note, I really enjoy Dave Ward's blog; I just wish he would post a little more often; he is also very good about responding to email and Twitter if you would like to contact him directly. He is also here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I've already begun running through this idea. His code is in a zip and runs like a treat but it's in C# which I'm not familiar with. I ran it through the Teleric Converter but it's working working correctly in VB.NET. No errors just won't hit the second page.

Comment: I found the error, it was in the html markup. AutoEventWireup was set to false, once set to true it kicked off in VB. I'll be reading his blog more, very informative. And thank you Karl, savior of the day! lol

Comment: @TylerAdkins - glad it worked out for you, yeah he has some pretty good stuff on his site for ASP.NET AJAX and jQuery. Good luck to you. :-)